# list of array assigned to be used in FOR loop mysql query php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

This just an example i have a mysql query and i have a array of condition for a query..

```
$b = array(Jan, Feb, March);
$c = array(idle, active);

$hr_ne3 = "SELECT any statement WHERE b = 'Jan' AND c = 'idle'";
$result_hr_ne3 = mysql_query($hr_ne3);
$ne_hr3=mysql_fetch_array($result_hr_ne3,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

so the condition of the query will be follow the array.. 
Jan->idel, Feb->idel, March->idel 
then continue with 
Jan->active, Feb->active, March->active

Anyone have idea and guide to query out this kind of flow?
The table layout should be looks like [THIS](https://prnt.sc/fxxprh)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: yes i am facing alot of parameters problem since iam trying on xampp, and make it live in server which using old version of php and it give allot of trouble

Comment: Your server has to be positively archaic (PHP 4?) to not support mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split to two loop

```
$b = array("Jan", "Feb", "March");
$c = array("idle", "active");

foreach($b as $itemB) {
  $hr_ne3 = "SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = '".$itemB."' AND c = '".$c[0]."'";
  $result_hr_ne3 = mysql_query($hr_ne3);
  $ne_hr3=mysql_fetch_array($result_hr_ne3,MYSQL_ASSOC);
  //echo $hr_ne3."\n";
}

foreach($b as $itemC) {
  $hr_ne3 = "SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = '".$itemC."' AND c = '".$c[1]."'";
  $result_hr_ne3 = mysql_query($hr_ne3);
  $ne_hr3=mysql_fetch_array($result_hr_ne3,MYSQL_ASSOC);
  //echo $hr_ne3."\n";
}
```

if you uncomment `echo` you will get

```
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'Jan' AND c = 'idle'
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'Feb' AND c = 'idle'
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'March' AND c = 'idle'
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'Jan' AND c = 'active'
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'Feb' AND c = 'active'
SELECT any statement WHERE AND b = 'March' AND c = 'active'
```

Comment: can i put this two loop inside another one loop? mean i have another array for that one..

Comment: Tested code above it works but looks messy since my table format is like
[link]http://prntscr.com/fxxprh

Comment: still cannot figure out since my table have a rowspan it make the whole table out of align

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$b = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'March');
$c = array('idle', 'active');
$result_array = array();
foreach($c as $key){
    foreach ($b as $value) {
        $query          = "SELECT any statement WHERE b = '".$value."' AND c = '".$key."'";
        $result         = mysql_query($query);
        $result_array[] = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($result_array);
}
?>
```